# Drawing circuit to compute mux

Tags: multiplexer, drawing

Ok so I've been working on this problem for a while now. I've been given

**mux**(\$p_{11}, p_{10}, p_{01}, p_{00}, x_1, x_0) = p_{x_1x_0}.\$

I found the boolean formula to be:

\$(!(x_1x_0))p_{11} + ((!x_1)x_0)P_{10} + (x_1(!x_0))p_{01} + (x_1x_0)p_{00}. \$

My question is what would the circuit that computes *mux* look like using only **and**, **or**, and **not** gates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first term in your Sum-of-products is incorrect.

Comment: Really? What would it be?

Comment: !(ab) = !a b + a !b + !a !b, so your first term is actually 3 product terms.

Answer (score 1):

It would have complement generators for x0 and x1, 3-input ands with the appropriate inputs, and a 4-input or at the end.

This should get you started:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8zf2Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>